# Where to put the data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

In MongoDB, I have a collection called `users`. I have to store `points` for each user. Points may increase or decrease over time. If I had to use a SQL-DB then I would have stored the points in a separate table called `UserPoint` with these columns:

```
UserID, DateTime, CurrentPoint, TotalPoint, Description
```

I would need to get the latest `TotalPoint` for a given User and insert new rows in the `UserPoint` table too frequently. How to do the same in No-SQL or MongoDB? Should I create a new collection called `points` or should I add a new object-array field in `users` collection?

```
{
   points: [
     {
        datetime: XXX,
        currentPoint: YYY,
        totalPoint: ZZZ,
        descriotion: WWW
     },...
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this case a parent referencing would make sense.

And since the totalPoints can be calculated from points in the app, there is no need to keep it in one of the models.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  ...
});

const pointSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  datetime: date,
  currentPoint: number,
  description: String,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: [true, "Point must have a user"]
  }
});
```

So our User model is simple, and adding a point to the points collection is quite easy (just a regular insert,  no array manipulation)